# find in a file where sign of a column entry changes and print first line where this happens

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python, numeric-data

I have multiply files, each with three columns. I would like to monitor where a given column entries first change sign (i.e negative to positive) so that I save that row where this first happens to another file. In the example below, i want to monitor the change in sign in the first column.

```
-1 2 4  
-4 3 5  
-2 4 6
1  2 4  
2  4 5    
2  3 4      
-4 5 6  
-3 4 6
```

The code should save the line **-2 4 6** to another file.

Comment: You only care about the first column's sign change?

Comment: Yes only first column sign and then get the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change is *always* from negative to <strike>positive</strike> non-negative, this should do. It just prints the previous line and exits when it sees a non-negative value in field 1 (change the number in `$1` to look at another field):

```
$ awk '$1 >= 0 { print prev; exit; } { prev = $0; }' < inputfile
-2 4 6
```

If the change can be either way, we'll need to store the sign on the previous line and compare against that (here, the field number is required in two places, so it's taken from the variable set by `-vfield=1`):

```
$ awk -vfield=1 'function sign(x) { if (x < 0) return -1; return +1; }
      NR != 1 && sign($field) != prevsign { print prevline; exit; }
      { prevline = $0; prevsign = sign($field) }' < inputfile
```

In both cases, you can of course use `> outputfile` to redirect the output to another file.